# How to forbid the menu item selection by right click?

Tags: linux, gnome, mouse

Clicking the right button prompts a context menu, then we can choose an item from the menu by a left or right click. However, it's really boring that we can use right click to select the item. Sometimes when I prompt the menu by right click, the item at the cursor is selected in the meantime (maybe the mouse is not so good or I shaked my finger).

Is it possible to prevent the usage of right click to choose a context menu item? (I'm not sure if I have make the problem clear)